# Relation between improper Riemann integral and lebesgue integral on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis

We know Lebesgue integral is not a generalization of improper Riemann integral on $\mathbb{R}$. Now, I need a more general theorem on $\mathbb{R}^n$, satisfying a weak enough condition, then improper Riemann integral on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equal to Lebesgue integral. Can you tell me some reference about it.

Comment: If $f \ge 0$ and the reimann improper integral exists then the lebesgue improper integral exists and is the same value

Comment: I guess we can start by saying that if $f$ is improper Riemann integrable but $|f|$ is not, then $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable @NickE